# Openlayers React rotate polygon feature

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I have a simple react/openlayers here(https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/Lx44yc3m/) that I have setup to demonstrate my problem.

1. I have a simple map which is currently working.
2. A tool that allows a user to draw a polygon which is currently working.
3. A tool that allows the user to move the polygon which is currently working.
4. A tool that allows the user to rotate the polygon, which is not currently working - this is where I need the help and have included the other tools incase they help anyone see how my app is working.

In my sample app if you draw a polygon, select the rotate tool and click on the polygon that you have drawn it will rotate the polygon by 20 degrees - so I know there is a rotate function. I want the user to click and drag or click and display a handle to drag to give them good control over the rotation.

`feature.element.getGeometry().rotate(0.349066, c);` is currently doing the rotation.

So what I don't know is how do I take the users input, lets say `mousedown`, detect that they are moving the mouse and use the values in the `rotate()` function to change the rotation of the polygon?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### EDIT:

Here is an example of what I mean about the bounding box/handles on the polygon: [image]

Comment: Hi again, this is one solution I have just come up with (https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/k7nfzgfu/). but ideally I would like to have a handle or bounding box appear when the polygon is hovered. And when that handle is dragged the polygon would move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ol-ext project provides a set of cool extensions including an interaction to move/rotate objects. 
Have a look at the example: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.transform.html
@+

Comment: This is awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Haven't had time to implement it yet but this will fit may case exactly.

Comment: I have finally had time to test this and get it working with React (here: https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/zsyr2wzg/) :-) @viglino-jean-marc your plugin/extension library is awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

to display an handle when hovering, detect it with a pointer event:

```
  map.on('pointermove', (evt) => {
    if (evt.dragging) {
      return;
    }
    const pixel = this.map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);

    const feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
      pixel,
      someFeature => someFeature, // return first element
      { hitTolerance: 2 }
    );

    // control an css class somehwere or use style.
    map.getTarget().style.cursor = feature ? 'pointer' : '';
  });
```

for the real-live rotation:

1. user holds the mouse down, triggering `mousedown`
2. store the startPosition of the cursor and toggle a "isRotating" flag
3. in the `pointermove` event (see above), (if isRotating) use the position to calculate the relative change to the startPosition to update the rotation
4. (probably optional) when mouseup is triggered, apply the final rotation and toggle the isRotating flag back

Comment: Any suggestions on identifying if the mouse is rotated clockwise/ counter-clockwise ?

Comment: @KarthikBhat I guess you should ask a new question for that. Though generally speaking I don't think it's possible to detect rotation of the mouse at all